# Why does Play Store still show the feature even I disable it in the manifest xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have added the following line into the manifest file but Play Store still shows Microphone in the features and it also says "XX devices removed" for the new APK file. (because of the microphone requirement)

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.MICROPHONE" android:required="false"/>
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is because you're using `android.hardware.MICROPHONE` instead of `android.hardware.microphone`. Hardware features are all lowercase.

Since it's not finding a matching `<uses-feature>` tag, it uses the implicit feature from the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission.

Answer (score 1):

You still are requesting that you are using the feature but saying the device does not need the feature to use the app.

therefore the feature will show up because you still use it even though you dont require it.

If you dont want it to show then dont use the microphone

Comment: I don't use the microphone but because of the Visualizer and Equalizer, I had to include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>` which automatically adds "microphone"

Comment: This isn't right. If the feature is listed as `required="false"`, Google Play won't filter based on that feature. It may show up on the list of features, but it won't remove devices.

Comment: @Geobits all I am talking about is why it is showing in the list not why devices are being deleted

Comment: I am facing the same problem. My app records with microphone, but it can work without microphone too. Then in my manifest I put
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
but google play still shows that my app require a microphone!!!